# draggable scrollbar on form flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to place a draggable scrollbar on my flutter `Form`, so the web users can click and drag to the screen bottom. The flutter `Scrollbar` class is fine for touchscreen devices, for mouses is not!

I've tried using [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar), however it only accepts `ListView` as child.

Here is my current code structure:

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My form'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(...),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: We can look for Flutter-provided updates on this here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31753

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Draggable Scrollbar you can try using `ListView.builder` with only 1 item which is your form, as shown below.

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My form'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: DraggableScrollbar.rrect(
                controller: myScrollController,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: myScrollController,
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Form();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunally, it doesn't work. There is no error building the code, but it doesn't show up the form content! I tested it for IOS and web. Any ideia?

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable with [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar) which you tried already. The idea is not to wrap the `Form` widget with it, but wrap its child `widget` which can be a list since `Form` expects a single child. Here is working example available in this live [dart-pad](https://dartpad.dev/53c1e3d7fcc8865b8cdab7b57bd45236).

The core idea is as follows.

1. Create you Form widget as usual.
2. Instead of creating a `Column` of form contents like `TextFormField` wrap them in `ListView` widget with its children as form fields.
3. Create a `ScrollController` as required by the `DraggableScrollBar.xyz` of you choice and pass it this `_myFormScrollController`.
4. Pass the same `_myFormScrollController` to the `ListView`'s controller parameter.

This should enable a scrollable form with scrollbar.

```dart
        Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: DraggableScrollbar.rrect(  
            controller: _scrollController,
            alwaysVisibleScrollThumb: true,
            child: ListView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              children: [
                ...List<Widget>.generate(15, (i) => TextFormField(
                  controller: TextEditingController()..text='Field $i',
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter some text';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                )),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Some notes about the live dart-pad:

- ***contains entire source of the draggable_scrollbar widget. All credit goes to it developer***.
- The code creates a new `TextEditingContorller` for each `TextFormField` which is not advisable. It serves only a cosmetic purpose in this example.
- The core logic is only in the `MainScreen` widget

> **Note:** I completely copied the draggable scroll bar code into the dartpad as its not possible to import packages in dartpad yet. ‍♂️